# Json output change

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

My database(mysql)

```
product_name

    ID   product_name   qty
    1     item a      5
    2     item b      4
    3     item c      3
```

My php code

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$query="select*from product_name";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die("Error in Selecting " .mysqli_error($db));
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arrey[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($arrey);
?>
```

Output is

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "productname": "item a",
    "qty": "5"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "productname": "item b",
    "qty": "4"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "productname": "item c",
    "qty": "3"
}]
```

I have to face data like bellow

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "message": "Data fetched successfully!",
    "data": [{
            "id": "1",
            "productname": "item a",
            "qty": "5"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "productname": "item b",
            "qty": "4"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "productname": "item c",
            "qty": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: If you only want a few fields from a table, try not to use `select * from` and just list the columns you want `select id, productname, qty from`.  You can then use `mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` to fetch all the rows in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  should add  your array in an header array

```
    $myArray =  ['status' =>"true", 
                    "message"=> "Data fetched successfully!", 
                    'data' =>$arrey];
```

.

```
   <?php
      include("connect.php");
      $query="select*from product_name";
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die("Error in Selecting " .mysqli_error($db));
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $arrey[]=$row;
      }

      $myArray =  ['status' =>"true", 
                    "message"=> "Data fetched successfully!", 
                    'data' =>$arrey];
      echo json_encode($myArray);

  ?>
```